# Queries gone haywire since update to 3.8.1

Tags: database, mysql, debug

I have a WordPress install on a dedicated server with decent memory (upwards of 8GB)

Since upgrading to 3.8, I started getting mysql disconnects/timeouts, better known as

> MySQL server has gone away

I enabled error_log for a bit, i.e.

```
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
```

This resulted in an immense file - basically the error_log grows by about a GB every 4 minutes or so.

I AM caching queries

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 8M
query_cache_size = 512M
```

I was able to temporarily fix the issue by setting

```
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

Then I installed [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) and checked queries on homepage. Debug Bar tells me there are 729 queries!

The slow ones are:

```
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'
```

> require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'),
>   require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'),
>   wp_not_installed, is_blog_installed, wp_load_alloptions #1

**7.5ms**

```
UPDATE`wp_options`SET`option_value`...WHERE`option_name`= 'wpseo_titles'
```

> require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   include('/themes/weaver-ii-pro/page.php'), weaverii_get_header,
>   get_header, locate_template, load_template,
>   require_once('/themes/weaver-ii-pro/header.php'), wp_title,
>   apply_filters('wp_title'), call_user_func_array,
>   WPSEO_Frontend->title, apply_filters('wpseo_title'),
>   call_user_func_array, WPSEO_Frontend->title_test_helper, update_option

**55.0ms**

```
UPDATE`wp_options`SET`option_value`...WHERE`option_name`= 'wpseo_titles'
```

> require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   include('/themes/weaver-ii-pro/page.php'), weaverii_get_header,
>   get_header, locate_template, load_template,
>   require_once('/themes/weaver-ii-pro/header.php'), wp_head,
>   do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array,
>   Facebook_Open_Graph_Protocol::add_og_protocol,
>   apply_filters('fb_meta_tags'), call_user_func_array,
>   WPSEO_OpenGraph->facebook_filter, WPSEO_OpenGraph->og_title,
>   WPSEO_Frontend->title, apply_filters('wpseo_title'),
>   call_user_func_array, WPSEO_Frontend->title_test_helper, update_option

**56.4ms**

```
UPDATE`wp_options`SET`option_value`...WHERE`option_name`= 'wpseo_titles'
```

> require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   include('/themes/weaver-ii-pro/page.php'), weaverii_get_footer,
>   get_footer, locate_template, load_template,
>   require_once('/themes/weaver-ii-pro/footer.php'), wp_footer,
>   do_action('wp_footer'), call_user_func_array,
>   WPSEO_Frontend->flush_cache, WPSEO_Frontend->title,
>   apply_filters('wpseo_title'), call_user_func_array,
>   WPSEO_Frontend->title_test_helper, update_option

**56.0ms**

```
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'dismissed_update_core' LIMIT 1
```

> require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   include('/themes/weaver-ii-pro/page.php'), weaverii_get_footer,
>   get_footer, locate_template, load_template,
>   require_once('/themes/weaver-ii-pro/footer.php'), wp_footer,
>   do_action('wp_footer'), call_user_func_array, wp_admin_bar_render,
>   do_action_ref_array, call_user_func_array, wp_admin_bar_updates_menu,
>   wp_get_update_data, get_core_updates, get_site_option, get_option

**9.6ms**

I do have lots (~50) plugins installed, and I use [Weaver II Pro](http://pro.weavertheme.com/) theme. Most of these plugins are essential to get what I need out of WordPress (I use WordPress as a CMS). This is a live install so I can't really disable everything and then enable one by one to see what's breaking things (if not core). Is there another way to figure out the problem by looking at the Debug Bar's output?

Comment: Your `wp_options` table seems to be really large. Can you give me statistics to this?

Comment: Try turning off WPSEO.

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions. Edit your original question with any additional information you might have.

Comment: @fischi What stats do you need? How can I get them?

Comment: @Otto I am quite scared of doing that. Not sure if deactivating the plugin would save my settings or not. BTW, it is one of the popular plugins...have you seen it cause this sort of issue before?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Not a duplicate of the other one. That particular issue was solved by setting max_allowed_packet. Gave some background info that's same as the other...but this is a bit wider I guess, which is why I created new...I figure this is not just about MY issue, but how useful the questions can be to other folks...from that perspective, 2 issues...2 questions...hmm?

Comment: No, I've never used the WPSEO plugin, so I don't know what it could be doing, but from your examples there, I would recommend turning that plugin off temporarily and seeing the difference.